# Run python script from django app, display window on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I want to run an app from Django and have window open on the Raspberry Pi screen.

On the Pi I have a Django project running on the web server.
The Pi is running Raspbian
I have a small game app called game.py on the Rpi.
I want to be able to run the game.py from a tablet via a browser.

I guess in other words can I launch a python app from a tablet using Django and have the app displayed on the RPi screen? If possible would this be handled through Django views.py file?

I added this to my views.py.

```
import os

def my_game(request):
    os.system("python mygame.py")
    return render(request, 'controller_home.html')
```

added to urls.py

```
 url(r'^mygame/$', views.my_game, name='mygame'),
```

when I call /mygame in the browser address bar, it pulls up the page controller_home.html but it doesn't appear to run the mygame.py.  I used ps -aux to see if it was running

Comment: Browser can run only javaScript, not Python. You can only make screenshot of game/desktop and display in browser or record game/desktop and stream video. But both are complex problem.

Comment: if you only start game then use `import game` or `os.system("python game.py")` - eventually run it in thread.